# Frameworks cause memory leak in macOS

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, instruments

I have a project with an empty main() function.

Just by linking frameworks to my project (e.g. *ImageIO.framework*) Instruments lists un-freed memory allocations after shutdown of my application.

[image: Xcode Instruments]

1) Can I hide persistent memory allocations in Instruments which were created by Apple Frameworks, so I can concentrate on my memory leaks?

2) Is this intended because Apple knows the OS cleans up afterwards anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1 - choose "All Heap allocations" at Allocation Type (and not All Heap & Anonymous VM).

Regarding 2 - even Apple has some memory leaks..but yes, it's would be freed after app's shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can be the owner of an object which is created by a framework. Read [Instruments User Guide, Find Memory Leaks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html).

2) Yes. Singletons and objects that can be reused, like `NSColorPanel`, aren't deallocated. Also, it is faster to quit the app without cleaning up. For example, from the documentation of `NSManagedObject`: "Core Data does not guarantee that dealloc will be called in all scenarios (such as when the application quits)".